# I cant open sqlite database

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am required to get sqlitedb in located here

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zxl8ocql.default.places.sqlite.
```

The following code works while accessing Google Chrome data:

```
 private const string PathToChromeData = @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History";
 private const string PathToFirefoxData = @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zxl8ocql.default\places.sqlite";



  string pathh = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), PathToFirefoxData);

                using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + pathh + ";Version=3;New=False;;"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select * from moz_places", connection);

   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

So I slightly changed it for getting Firefox data. However I am getting this exception:

```
unable to open database file
```

Then I have checked  few similar threads on SO. And realized that Firefox locks this database  while its running. And I closed the Firefox even changed the location of database. I checked the connection string, but it seems correct. What is wrong here?

Comment: Try removing "\" from `PathToFireFoxData` after `default`.

Comment: Try to open it with sqlite browser to check whether the format of the db they use is compatible

Comment: If you can't you can share a link to the file so that we can try

Comment: Cauz i dont hav mozilla

Comment: Sayka I think you are right.Open up sqlite browser As you suggested And notice that there is no  table inside I dont understand There is a runnig example here    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4fz7-KQSFY

Comment: Have you checked Task Manager, any instances of mozilla, or its service is running?

Comment: Because, when i use this sqlite database in my android applications, when these dbs are busy with the application, and if i try to copy the db from my phone to computer, it gets copied with 1 or 2mb showing but still without any tables. And when i close the application service, i can view those tables

Comment: I have just checked the location of the db  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zxl8ocql.default\places.sqlite   and realized that It is 0 KB  And  no instance in the TaskManager

Answer (score 0):

You got a size of 0 KB, because you are searching the history file in the wrong directory.

Replace `Local` with `Roaming` and you will get the original `places.sqlite` file.

The new path would be 
`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zxl8ocql.default\places.sqli‌​te`.

Why you found a db of 0 KB in Local?

When you try to open a db file with API, if file does not exist it will create a new empty file. That is why you found a 0 KB sqlite file in local.

Well I am also getting the same issue as described above.

I am looking in to it. I will post a solution if I got.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad that I figured it out and fixed it.

The problem was with the sql version; db was created with a higher version and I was trying to open it with a lower version of sqlite.

It should be handled and at least they should display a proper message.

To open firefox db you require sqlite version 3.8.x.